# how to generate uncorrelated random numbers in repeated calls in parallel?

Tags: c, random, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to write a function which will be repeatedly called by other functions many times. Inside this function it is supposed to generate a lot of random numbers and this part will be treated in parallel. If only for one run, the seed can be chosen differently for each thread, so that the random numbers will be uncorrelated. However, if this function will be called the 2nd time, it seems that the random numbers will repeat unless the seed will be again changed during the later calls.

So my question is, is there a good way to generate the random numbers or reset the seed so that the random numbers generated by repeated calls to this function and also by different threads are really random?

I need to do this in openMP. Is it possible to store the state of the generator for each thread separately after each call of the function, so that when the next time the function is called, the random number generator start from the last state and continue to generate uncorrelated numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you need one per thread, why not share the same generator?

Answer (score 0):

First use strong random number generators like MT. To solve your threading problem make one generator guarded by a mutex that will generate seeds for each thread. Then on each thread use a different generator.
The key is to initialize the minimum number of times you need, for that you will probably need a program global for the seed generator and thread local storage for each thread's generator.

Comment: Unfortunately if this is for a simulation where the results need to be statistically valid, this isn't good enough. (The reason is that there is significant probability that two or more thread generators will end up in start states that happen to be nearby in the rng cycle). You'd need to seek out a rng specifically for multi-threaded problems. Of course for a non-critical application like a game what you propose is fine.

Comment: I should have said that parallel random number generation is a topic of current research.  See for example http://sprng.cs.fsu.edu/. Hope this is of help.

Comment: How to " make one generator guarded by a mutex that will generate seeds for each thread" so that there are no correlations between some threads in different calls?

Comment: @user1446948: it's so that each thread can have its own generator and they won't have to lock on each other. Unguarded generator will quickly become deterministic if used on many threads at once. There won't be problems if you use a strong generator.

Comment: I agree with @Gene. A way to avoid that problem is to have a whole family of RG where you can also vary the coefficients such that they follow completely different cycles. You would then not only seed the RG differently per thread, but also chose the coefficients differently.

Comment: This is roughly what parallel rng's do!